# ViewModel not updating with data change

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, observable

So, this is my first time using architecture components in Android. I'm trying to create a ViewModel that will keep returning the latest location which can be used by UI elements. I've created a viewModel like this:

```
    class LocationViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
        val currentLocation = MutableLiveData<Location?>()

        init {
            val ctx = getApplication<Application>().applicationContext
            val fusedLocationProvider = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(ctx)

            val locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            locationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY
            locationRequest.interval = 5000
            locationRequest.fastestInterval = 2000

            val builder = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest)
            val client = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(ctx)

            client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build()).addOnFailureListener {
                currentLocation.postValue(null)
            }

            val locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
                override fun onLocationResult(p0: LocationResult?) {
                    super.onLocationResult(p0)
                    p0 ?: return
                    currentLocation.postValue(p0.lastLocation)
                }
            }

            fusedLocationProvider.requestLocationUpdates(
                locationRequest,
                locationCallback,
                Looper.getMainLooper()
            )
        }
    }
```

And I observe this ViewModel in an activity, like so

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        private lateinit var locationText: TextView

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

            locationText = findViewById(R.id.locationText)

            val location = ViewModelProviders.of(this)[LocationViewModel::class.java]
            location.currentLocation.observe(this, Observer { resutlLocation: Location? ->
                locationText.text =
                    if (resutlLocation != null) "Lat: ${resutlLocation.latitude} Long: ${resutlLocation.longitude}" else "Null"
            })
        }
    }
```

The TextView doesn't even gets updated once. How things like these should be done? What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you debug whether the currentLocation.postValue(p0.lastLocation) is being called?

Comment: I haven't but I do think its not being called

Comment: It might be the problem, try to change to different data input to verify

Answer (score 0):

In View View model create function like this.

```
fun initdata() {

    val ctx = getApplication<Application>().applicationContext
    val fusedLocationProvider = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(ctx)

    val locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
    locationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY
    locationRequest.interval = 5000
    locationRequest.fastestInterval = 2000

    val builder = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest)
    val client = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(ctx)

    client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build()).addOnFailureListener {
        currentLocation.postValue(null)
    }

    val locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(p0: LocationResult?) {
            super.onLocationResult(p0)
            p0 ?: return
            currentLocation.postValue(p0.lastLocation)
        }
    }

    fusedLocationProvider.requestLocationUpdates(
        locationRequest,
        locationCallback,
        Looper.getMainLooper()
    )
}
```

then use like this

```
  val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this)[LocationViewModel::class.java]
  viewModel.initdata()
```

**Edit 1**

You can lazy initialize like this way

```
private val users:MutableLiveData<Location?> by lazy {
    MutableLiveData().also {
      initdata()
    }
}
```

more details refer [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)

Comment: This looks very hacky, the documentation says to use AndroidViewModel when we need context inside ViewModel.

Comment: That case you can use Edit answer